# Is there any difference in meaning beteen "hang on" and "hang in" in the sense of continuing despite difficulties?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference in meaning between *hang on* and *hang in* in the sense of continuing despite difficulties? For example:

> The patient is in a coma. He's **hanging in** there.
>
> The patient is in a coma. He's **hanging on**.

Answer (score 1):

*Hang in there* is a a phrase, I don't think I've ever heard anyone say *hang in* on its own (unless they were literally talking about something hanging in a closet or wherever). If you said *hang in* people would probably just assume you meant *hang on*!

Comment: So what's the difference between "hang in there" and "hang on"?

Comment: *Hang in there* is a positive comment you'd say to someone who's having a tough time for whatever reason. It basically means don't lose hope, keep going, it will get better! (You've seen the "hang in there baby" posters right?) *Hang on* doesn't sound as positive and light, it's more serious, like if the person gives up something bad will happen. Your examples mean the same thing, but the first one has a slightly lighter, more optimistic tone that's sometimes appropriate. But you wouldn't really saying "hanging in there for dear life". (*Hold on* can also mean *wait*)